# Loopback search on all fields

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, loopbackjs

I am using `loopback` as a backend now I wish to be able to search across all fields in the table

For instance, take the following table fields:

```
id, name, title, created, updated
```

Now say I want to search across the table using the following string "`nomad`"

However, I am unsure how to structure the query

I have attempted:

```
{"where": {"keywords": {"inq": ["nomad"]}}}
```

However, this just returns all results

So how do I do this? :)

If it matters my database is a `postgresql`

Comment: can you tell us more about the app? is it angular? there are some differences if so

Comment: @JordanHendrix Hello yes the app is an angular app however i am not using loopback angular. Loopback is used as my backend api so the calls to it should be fairly "normal"

Comment: Any luck so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loopback is not where you need to look at. It's just a framework with universal ORM / ODM to connect to your DB and expose is with a query language over rest. You probably need in your case to add a `text` index in your postgresql database. By indexing all your desired properties into a text index, you'll be able to perform search in your DB.

Here is the documentation. 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch.html

You can still achieve your goal using loopback ORM with something like

`{"where": {"prop1": {"regex": "nomad"}, "prop2": {"regex": "nomad"}}}`

but your DB will die in few queries ...

Answer (score 4):

You can use loopback's case insensitive regex to search the database for the value.

**Example**:

```
Fields: [id, name, title, created, updated]

let whereCondition = {id: {regexp: '/nomad/i'}, name: {regexp: '/nomad/i'}}

app.models.ModelName.find({
  where: whereCondition
});
```

Refer the loopback documentation url below:
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Where-filter.html#regular-expressions

Answer (score 1):

You can try using **RegExp** :

```
 let searchField = "nomad";
 var search = new RegExp(searchField, 'i');
{"where": {"id":search,"name" : search}
```

I have use **Aggregate** in **LookUp** to **Search** .

Example :

```
 let searchField = "anyname";
     var searchCond = [];
         if (searchField) {
                        var search = new RegExp(searchField, 'i');
                        searchCond.push({ "id": search },{ "name": search });
                    }
```

//Depending on your other condition you add at aggregate :

```
    var modelCollection = Model.getDataSource().connector.collection(Model.modelName);
    modelCollection.aggregate([{
                        $match: {
                            $or: searchCond
                        }
                    }], function(err, data) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    return callback(null, data);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get a querying function that will transverse through your DB and return back your data from the table.

Eg:

```
Account.find({where: {name: 'John'}, limit: 3}, function(err, accounts) { /* ... */ });
```

Or

```
{where: {property: value}}
```

You can get to discover more from [Loopback Querying data](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Querying-data.html), [Loopback Where filter](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Where-filter.html) and [postgresql RETURN QUERY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING).